# requestFileSystem in Cordova 3.4 fails with "Class not found" error

Tags: android, apache, cordova

hoping anyone can figure this out, have been battling with this issue the whole day.
I'm trying to browse through folders on the file system to select a file, but I cannot seem to connect to the file system.

When ever I call "window.requestFileSystem", the error callback returns a "Class not found" error. Going into Cordova's "requestFileSystem" function, I notice the "Class not found" is returned during the exec() call (where I can't trace it).
Did anyone get past this problem, or know how to fix it?
I am aware it's listed on several forums, but the fixes suggested there don't work for me.

As far as I can see, all the plugins are there. Installed using Cordova CLI, they appear in the plugin folder. I do wonder if the file plugin is actually loaded, not sure how I can verify that..

- org.apache.cordova.console
- org.apache.
- cordova.device org.apache.cordova.file
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

www/index.html

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Init when we're good and ready.
        function onLoad(){document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, true);}

        // Init :)
        function init(){
            // window.requestFileSystem is recognized, so far so good.
            window.requestFileSystem(1, 0, function(fileSystem){
                alert('success');
            }, function(e){
                // 'e' is an object, {code: 'Class not found'}
                alert('Error accessing local file system');
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        ...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.fwd.cwptakeonsheetsv1" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>CWPTakeOnSheetsV1</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />



    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file" />
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Cordova's requestFileSystem.js

```
/**
 * Request a file system in which to store application data.
 * @param type  local file system type
 * @param size  indicates how much storage space, in bytes, the application expects to need
 * @param successCallback  invoked with a FileSystem object
 * @param errorCallback  invoked if error occurs retrieving file system
 */
var requestFileSystem = function(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    argscheck.checkArgs('nnFF', 'requestFileSystem', arguments);
    var fail = function(code) {
        errorCallback && errorCallback(new FileError(code));
    };

    if (type < 0) {
        fail(FileError.SYNTAX_ERR);
    } else {
        // if successful, return a FileSystem object
        var success = function(file_system) {
            if (file_system) {
                if (successCallback) {
                    // grab the name and root from the file system object
                    var result = new FileSystem(file_system.name, file_system.root);
                    successCallback(result);
                }
            }
            else {
                // no FileSystem object returned
                fail(FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR);
            }
        };
        // The error happens in exec()
        exec(success, fail, "File", "requestFileSystem", [type, size]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin with the CLI? I only saw similar message when developping my own plugins and forgetting to add `<feature>` in config.xml

Comment: I did, tried uninstalling and reinstalling both 'org.apache.cordova.file' and 'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer' (reinstalling went succesfully). It didn't make a difference though. When I alert 'FileSystem', 'DirectoryEntry', 'File' or 'FileTransfer' it comes up with the corect functions, so I assume the module are loaded.

Comment: Wich config.xml file did you put in your question? `<feature>` lines should not be present in the root config.xml but be automatically added by the cli platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml by the cli when installing the plugins. Maybe you have the lines in double in the platform's config.xml?

Comment: Aha.. that makes sense. I did have them in the root config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved my problem. Here are the steps I did to get it working:

1. Moved all the JavaScript to the head-section of my *index.html* (including references to *.js* files).
2. Took all the feature-tags out of *config.xml*. My */platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml* still contains:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
3. Took all `alerts()` and custom debugging functions out of my code. I don't know if the delay caused issues or what, but it seems to have an effect.

I also noticed that if `window.requestFileSystem` is `undefined`, it is likely due to a JavaScript error which causes it not to load.

There's a good example of this [here](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/) - Thanks Ram for publishing this.

Thanks @QuickFix for your reply!

Comment: Tried, can only do it tomorrow :|

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem (at least in my case). I'd struggled with this one popping up over and over again:

**Simply open up plugins/android.json and move any entries under the 'config.xml' heading to the 'res/xml/config.xml' heading.**

I think this is an issue with certain plugins (in my case, Immersify) not having switched to the new config.xml location. After I fixed this, all of the 'missing' plugins magically appeared in my platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml file, and the 'class not found' errors disappeared.

Comment: Did you mean plugins/android.json? And also weirdly it worked for me when I did the opposite e.g. moved everything under "res/xml/config.xml" to be under "config.xml".

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the android.json that is generated in the plugins folder?
I had a similar problem because some 'not yet updated to 3.4' plugins like sqlite generated wrong directions in this file (which is used at build time). That lead into removing some other plugins from my actual config.xml